# One MutableData For Multiple WebServices

Tags: ios, json

I need to call a webService (JSON) and pass couple of its contents as parameter to second webService and then call second web service.
Can i use same Mutable Data for this.Like in the

```
-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
```

where i get the contents, i take the contents in the string and then clear the responseData and call the second webService from there itself.
**PS: It should take minimum time to fetch data for both WebService**
Is it possible ??
If so,  how can i achieve this.
Thank You.

Comment: `connectionDidFinishLoading:` is the last delegate method invoked from the underlaying connection. That is you can safely append to the mutable data object while executing the second request. Though, there is no need for this, since you can always append two `NSData` objects in order to get one.

Comment: May i know in which situation makes the app getting crash?

Answer (score -1):

You can use the same variable to hold the response data for two simultaneous services. when you call the second web services again it calls all the NSURLConnection delegate methods,there you have to do like this.

```
    -(void)connection:(NSURLConnection*)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse*)response {
        [self.webData setLength: 0];
        NSLog(@"Got Response");
    }
    -(void) connection:(NSURLConnection *) connection didReceiveData:(NSData *) data 
    {
        [self.webData appendData:data];
        NSLog(@"Got Data");
    }
    -(void) connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *) connection 
    {
        NSLog(@"Received Bytes: %d", [self.webData length]);
      // content needs to be segregated here and call the second service through custom delegate/block
    }
```

Here self.webData holds the value until the call the second web service. 
`didReceiveResponse` method initiated once your second service start to receive response where you have to clear your response variable like this '[self.webData setLength: 0]'

The content which you wants to send as parameter to next service needs to segregated from `connectionDidFinishLoading` method

Comment: Didn't you mean "two consecutive connections", instead "two simultaneous connections"?

Comment: Wesley :By any chance do i need to close the connection.If i go by the way youve said, my app is crashing abruptly.

Comment: how did you try to close the connection?

Comment: By declaring the connection object of First web service global, and taking its instance in the didFinish, i did [con close], before calling second webService with the SAME Connection...mi doing it right ???

Comment: i hope you initiate the second web service from -(void) connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *) connection after making the connection object.Okay,. so the problem might be in making the connection object from first JSON webservice.

Comment: Probably...what i did is initiated the first webService in VDL and that might not be an issue

Comment: Yes i did the same thing

Comment: then before calling second web service, how did you close your connection object? Is there [con close] method residing in NSURLConnection class?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38878/discussion-between-wesley-and-icodeatapple)